# Jupyter running slow and crashing

Tags: crash, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have a python script that implements a basic neural network for autoencoding images.  Basically it contains a loop that

- 1) multiplies some large matrices and
- 2) uses imshow's set_data() and draw() to update and display an
  image.

  The script runs just fine in Spyder (version 3.5) with Windows 8.  However, in Jupyter (both on Windows 8 and on my Ubuntu virtual machine) it runs quite slowly and crashes after a few minutes.  My copies of both Spyder and Jupyter are the ones that come with a standard Anaconda download.

> What might be causing this performance difference?  Is there a way to
>   fix the problem with Jupyter?

[*Note: To get the script to work in Jupyter, I had to change some things.  Rather than using `draw(),` I used "`display.clear_output(wait=True)`" followed by "`display.display(plt.gcf())`".  I also added `"%matplotlib notebook"` at the top of the script.  It seems unlikely to me that these changes are the cause of the performance difference, but I thought I should mention them for completeness.*]